# Java generics for defining a graph

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

(Full disclosure, This is for homework.)

So I have been given a Vertex class with which to build a graph and perform some standard graph algorithms. Here's part of the vertex class we were given (This classes cannot be changed, i'll try and make it clear what can and cannot be modified for the assignment):

```
public static final class Vertex<V>
{
    private final String vertex;
    private final V vertexData;

    protected Vertex(String v, V d) {
        vertex = v;
        vertexData = d;
    }

    ... //some methods
 }
```

The Vertex class is embedded defined in an interface `IGraph<V,E>` which has a method:

```
public void addVertex( String vertexName, V vertexData ) throws DuplicateVertexException {
```

In my implementation of this interface, I implement the method with the second parameter as an object (not precisely sure why, but I get an error if I don't) so I have the following:

```
//this is my code, and can be changed
public class Graph<V, E> implements IGraph{

    private boolean directed = false;
    private List<Vertex<V>> vertices = new ArrayList<Vertex<V>>();
    private List<Edge<E>> edges = new ArrayList<Edge<E>>();



    public void addVertex(String vertexName, Object vertexData) throws DuplicateVertexException {
        Vertex<V> vnew = new Vertex(vertexName, vertexData); //this is where I get a problem
        for(Vertex<V> x: vertices) {
            if(vertexName.equals(x.getVertexName())) {
                throw new DuplicateVertexException();
            }
        }
        vertices.add(vnew);
    }

    ... (other methods)
}
```

Basically I need some help with java generics here. If I try to put in

```
Vertex<V> vnew = new Vertex<V>(vertexName, vertexData);
```

I get eclipse telling me that `The constructor IGraph.Vertex<V>(String, Object) is undefined`. If I put in

```
Vertex<Object> vnew = new Vertex<Object>(vertexName, vertexData);
```

The I get a type mismatch when I want to add to my vertices List. The only thing that eclipse doesn't give me an error for is when I simply use a raw type

```
Vertex<Object> vnew = new Vertex(vertexName, vertexData);
```

But i've been encouraged not to use raw types, so I'd like to avoid this. So what exactly should I do here? is this line the problem or is there something else I should change, like the typing on my list of vertices?

Basically i'm trying to figure out how generic types work in this case, because it seems like the generic typing of the class wants me to make everything a `Vertex<V>`, but for the method signature i'm required to take an argument of type `object`.

Any help is hugely appreciated, also any other resources or good explanations regarding generic types are appreciated, i've read a few including the official oracle doumentation, but I'm still confused on certain parts of it.

Comment: You say: "If I try to put in

Vertex<V> vnew = new Vertex<V>(vertexName, vertexData);
I get eclipse telling me that The constructor IGraph.Vertex<V>(String, Object) is undefined."

Do you have a constructor with that signature defined?  If not, that is your error.

Comment: @DavidChoweller The only constructor for Vertex is the one in the post,  (protected Vertex(String v, V d) ) , so it doesn't have the <V> in the constructor. Does this mean that it's fine to use a raw type when instantiating a new Vertex?

Comment: You have defined vertexData as having a type of Object.  If you are only allowed to have that one constructor, then vertexData should be of type V.
`public void addVertex(String vertexName, V vertexData) throws DuplicateVertexException {`
And then:
        `Vertex<V> vnew = new Vertex(vertexName, vertexData);`

Comment: I've tried that actually, it gives me the error that "Name clash: The method addVertex(String, V) of type Graph<V,E> has the same erasure as addVertex(String, Object) of type IGraph but does not override it" I honestly have no idea what this means.

Comment: Just add @override on the line before before `public void addVertex(String vertexName, V vertexData) throws DuplicateVertexException {`

Comment: Assuming you really mean to override the addVertex method in IGraph.